# Using a loop to sequentially call a function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, flask

I am trying to create a function running inside a loop like this one:

```
list_a = [1, 5, 3, 4] 
list_b = ['great', 'awesome', 'good', 'nice'] 

for x in range (0, 4):
    def match(x):
        for i, j in zip(range(len(list_a)), range(len(list_b))):
            if x == j:
                second = list_b[j]
                break
        return second;

    print(match(x))
```

Output:

great

awesome

good

nice

The peculiarity in my case is that the elements from **list_a** are entries in a **DB table** and elements of **list_b** are a number of workbooks in an **Excel file**, and this had to run in a way in which each output from the function is the content of each workbook from that **Excel file**.

The problem comes here:

This output has to be displayed on a html template using **Flask**. My code goes like this:

```
alldetails1 - data from DB (list)
list_sales - data from Excel (list)

for x in range (len(all_details1)):
    def merchant(x):
        for i, j in zip(range(len(all_details1)), range(len(list_sales))):
            if x == j:
                data = list_sales[j]
                break
        return data
    merchant(x)

return render_template("supp_sales.html", list_sales_loop=data) 
#list_sales_loop is the variable I am using to generate the loop in the HTML file
```

This code is only displaying for me the content of the last workbook in the **HTML template**

The **HTML** interface where I display the buttons to call each instance of the function looks like this:

[image: HTML interface]

Comment: Why are you creating the function inside a loop?

Comment: The buttons you see on the image attached. By clicking on each of them a different workbook from the excel file should be displayed on the next HTML template. The rest of the data on the line is extracted from a DB and displayed there using a loop in Flask

Comment: Why are you *defining* the function inside the loop? That's confusing, does noting useful in this case, and is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: You really must provide a [mcve] Your code here would throw a `NameError` because `data` isn't defined when you reach `return render_template("supp_sales.html", list_sales_loop=data)`